# C-Wire for L8148J Thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Thanks for very informative videos.  Where do I connect C wire on the 8148J Aquastat to get 24 v for the Nest thermostat? Thanks

Comment: Videos? What videos? Please [edit] your question to include a picture of the wiring diagram, or, even better, a link to the instructions for your Aquastat that include the wiring diagram.